# DataTables call push array on column

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I have code to get date periode push array like this:

```
var dari = $("#tglfrom").val();
            var dateStart = new Date(dari);
            var sampai = $("#tglto").val();
            var dateEnd = new Date(sampai);
while (dateEnd >= dateStart) {
                   dateLoop.push( '{ title :"' +  (dateStart.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  dateStart.getFullYear() + '"}');
                      var newDate = dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getMonth() + 1);
                     dateStart.setMonth(dateStart.getMonth() + 1);
                }
```

and then I call my push array on DataTables on Column like this:

```
var Periode = dateLoop.join(', ');
    $('#datatable1').DataTable( {
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            Periode
        ]
});
```

But when I'm running, it show error it said:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '157' in {
>   title :"1/2016"}, { title :"2/2016"}, { title :"3/2016"}, { title
>   :"4/2016"}, { title :"5/2016"}, { title :"6/2016"}, { title
>   :"7/2016"}, { title :"8/2016"}

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: in `Periode` array you have a list of columns?